# Call to undefined function get_header()

Tags: php, wordpress

> Error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\Xampp\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 1

Index Code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar()?>
    <div id="left">

    <?php_while(have_posts()):?>

        <h2><?php the_title()?></h2>
        <?php the_content();?>


    <?php_endwhile();?>

    </div>

<?php get_footer()?>`
```

Comment: It's saying that your code is asking for the ```get_header()``` function, but that function is not defined. Is that all you have for your index.php?

Comment: this error is quite frequent on SO. Check these results and see in any solve your issue [Call to undefined function get_header()](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Call+to+undefined+function+get_header%28%29)

Comment: `C:\Xampp\xampp\htdocs\index.php` by looking at this path, you're writing the theme's `index.php` code in WordPress code root's `index.php` which you should not do. If you're new to WordPress please do some research on WordPress code file structure and WordPress theme file structure.

Answer (score 1):

the function `get_header()` is a wordpress theme function, you are calling it from:

`C:\Xampp\xampp\htdocs\index.php`

put this same code inside a wordpress theme and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

hi i faces same problem

go to "visit site" from wordpress bar menu
you will see the code run

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense, OP has posted the path from which we can clearly see that he is writing the code in wrong, and in a result he's getting errors as expected.